# Deeplink in Microsoft Teams(Redirection is fine but message is not getting populated in chat window)

Tags: microsoft-teams, message, deep-linking

I have implemented deeplink (Organisation Teams) to redirect to a specific bot and write a message in the chat window. This is working fine in Mobile teams and when it comes to Microsoft desktop or browser, the flow is getting redirected but the message is not written in the chat window.
Following is the format of the Deeplink Used

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/Chat/0/0?users=28:&message=Agent%20handoff

I sent a message along with the redirection id to an app.
Expectation: "Agent Handoff" message to populate in a new app that is deployed in Teams.
Result: New app window is being opened but there is no message in the chat window

And the thing is it's working fine in mobile and browser, but not in Desktop Teams

Comment: We currently have https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-teams which is deeplink to Teams chat. Here we need to give AAD UserPrincipalName to chat with that particular user. And we have https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/conversations to Navigate to a chat with the application.

Can you please let us know how you are forming the deeplink to bot's chat. What value are you passing for users

Comment: Actually, the link I mentioned above is the one we have implemented. In the "users" part instead of the user mail id, I have added the bot's conversation id, and this link when clicked redirects and populates the message in the chat window in Teams mobile, but the message is not getting populated on desktop Teams.

Comment: Can you please share [client logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/log-files#debug-logs) when you repro this issue? Please share at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com